# MySQL - How to combine data from two tables, using the value of one field as the filter to count values in another?

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I've been racking my brain on this one, and the solution is probably so simple but I just can't figure it out and have searched everywhere and can't find a solution to this specific problem.

I've got two tables - one contains an IP connections list, for example:

```
Connections_Table

src            dst
192.168.1.1    1.2.3.4
192.168.1.1    2.2.2.2
192.168.1.1    3.3.3.3
192.168.1.1    4.4.4.4
```

The other table contains a list of IP addresses, for example:

```
Bad_Ip_Addresses_Table

ip
7.8.9.4
3.2.1.4
77.8.99.4
2.2.2.2
18.7.9.8
```

Here's where I can't find how to build this query... I'm trying build a table that shows src and dst from the first table, and whether the 2nd table contains the dst from the first table. In other words:

```
Results_Table

src            dst        match
192.168.1.1    1.2.3.4    0
192.168.1.1    2.2.2.2    1
192.168.1.1    3.3.3.3    0
192.168.1.1    4.4.4.4    0
```

Here's probably the biggest catch: I've seen posts on SO where the solution involves creating a table and triggers. I can't do that - This would be an AWS Kinesis Analytics SQL statement:

Connections_Table is ingested live, and Bad_Ip_Addresses_Table is a CSV loaded from AWS S3. On each row ingested I need to perform a SQL statement against the CSV to find if the dst ip is in the CSV.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm confused.  Is this MySQL or Kinesis?  If not MySQL, then remove that tag (and probably SQL as well).

Comment: @GordonLinoff This is an AWS Kinesis Analytics SQL Statement using an S3 input file as Reference Data which can be queried using SQL statements to enrich Kinesis stream

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- In **MySQL**, you can `Left Join` from `Connections_Table` to `Bad_Ip_Addresses_Table`, such that all `dst` values from `Connections_Table` are considered (whether a matching row exists or not).
- You can then `Group By` on `src` and `dst`; and use `Count()` function to count the matches. Note that `Count(null) = 0`; so non-matching rows will return 0 (since there will be `null` values post the Left join).

In **MySQL**, try the following query:

```
SELECT
  ct.src,
  ct.dst, 
  COUNT(biat.ip) AS match 
FROM 
  Connections_Table AS ct 
LEFT JOIN Bad_Ip_Addresses_Table AS biat ON biat.ip = ct.dst 
GROUP BY ct.src, ct.dst
```

Comment: @nukalov happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a left join and count

```
select a.src, a.dst, count(b.ip)
from Connections_Table a
left join Bad_Ip_Addresses_Table  b on a.dst = b.ip 
group by a.src, a.dst
```